Any alternative to iframes or embed websites?
How can I insert any website into my application? I've tried using iframes, embeds and objects.
I can't find a way around the x-frame-options and content-security-policy headers blocking iframe requests.
Loading iframes through a proxy and removing those headers works only on some websites.

No. If it were possible to negate the x-frame-options and content-security-policy headers, they would be completely useless.

Why do you want to "insert any website into [your] application"?

@async-await is a feature of the app. Basically, in mobile, we use a webview, but in web, I haven't found a reliable solution.
Any idea how I could do this? I understand it's not possible to use iframes, so any other technology, mechanism, or service? Whatever, any possible solution?

What does this feature of your app do? You could always use a chrome extension, and you might be able to use your own browser if those are solutions.

I mean depending on what kind of feature it is, you could always just pipe a video stream of your server viewing the website.

The feature simply loads a website from the customer in a specific place on the app. I think using a Chrome extension is not the best solution at this time, because it needs to be usable in any browser.

I think this may go beyond the scope of a comment chain, you need a real discovery / exploration of your project requirements. The answer to your question is, you're not going to find another element like some z-frame that can bypass the security headers, because those security features are built into the browser for a reason. You'll need to build a workaround or rely on a service someone else built as workaround, and to know how to do that, I'd need more information regarding the purpose of this "embedded website". That's more than I can ask in the comments, good luck Pedro!

One workaround would be to use a backend server that fetches the html of the website you want to embed and then hosts that html on your own server. You'll need to also scan the html for other links and probably need to fetch the scipts and styles and host them yourself too, and replace the links in the original website to point to your server.
You also can't really do a normal get request from your browser due to CORS. This is why it would be easier to use a backend that fetches the HTML as if it's a browser visiting that website, and then your server sends the HTML to the client in the browser to have your website display it.

Interesting approach, I think it could work Thanks a lot.

Your probably violating a few local laws if you go this route.
